# Por que los items de listview no ocupan toda la fila - android

Tags: java, android

Tengo creado un listview en el cual lleno con informacion proveniente de una base de datos y les agrego una funcion clic a cada elemento

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.my_cutom_layout, villes);
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);
                listV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "On va à : "+(position+1)+" "+villes.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        String [] villeData = {getZone,""+(position+1) ,villes.get(position)};

                        intent.putExtra("ville", villeData);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
```

Pero al momento de visualizar los datos, el click solo funciona encima del texto y toda la fila no funciona el click

Comment: puedes poner el código del layout : R.layout.my_cutom_layout

Comment: Comparte el layout y una imagen de como se ve tu adapter funcionando.

Comment: ¿no ocupan toda la fila visualmente? o el problema es que no da clic en toda la fila.